# Segmentation fault and int 10h

Tags: assembly, nasm, interrupt

I wrote code which output string with parameters, but my programm crash with **Segmentation fault: 11**.

```
global main
segment .data
    col db 1
    row db 24
    msg db 'Hello'   
    len equ $-msg
segment .text
exit:
    mov eax, 0x1
    int 0x80
main:
    mov ah, 13h
    mov al, 1
    xor bh, bh
    mov cx, 5
    mov dh, 24
    mov dl, 20
    mov bp, msg
    int 10h

    call exit
```

P.S.: I use Unix (os x).

Comment: Which line did it crash on?

Comment: What do you expect `int 10h` to do ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H, I want print string in console on specific position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INT 10h is a real mode interrupt provided by BIOS and can be used only in a real-mode operating system like DOS or a bootloader but not Linux. For Linux you have to use INT 80h to access low-level functionality.

You should be able to print ANSI escape codes to put text anywhere on the screen on a terminal with ANSI support: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: Thanks, but how can I change postion cursor?

Comment: @LeeTwelve try reading the article I linked. you need to write a "special string" to the console containing ANSI escape codes. you can look up some sample codes for that. See examples here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html